# Find best practice to make dynamic layout React app in server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, server-side-rendering, dynamic-import

**Definition of our requested Dynamic App**

We Have to make an app with Dynamic Layout.
Our marketing team needs to change layout of page. for example ordering the components or maybe add new route to react app or maybe add or remove some component from some page.

**Technologies that we are using**
We are using **typescript** as our base language of create-react-app and redux for state management.

**My Solution**
My Solution for this is to generate .TSX file in server on changes come from a panel and build entire project with new files created by server.

I prefer to not use dynamic import, because user must waits for a api to get the page layout structure then client must import the components and after that every component request it's desired api call from server! Too much time waist!!

**Your Idea**
What do you think about this structure?
Is there any bottle neck that I may encounter? or maybe i didn't saw?

Comment: what are you describing is literally CMS, never generate a .tsx file on the server; as this will lead to dozens of other problems only to solve a single one. including how do you sync it with git? etc

EDIT: look into MDX and pass dynamic MDX strings to a single react page/route that loads dynamic routing

Comment: @ShanonJackson But what about import components dynamically? can i handle that too with MDX?